# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor how to define XPath

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I want to retreive the cityname and citycode and store it in one string variable. The image shows the precise location:

[image]

Google Chrome gave me the following XPath:

```
//*[@id="page"]/main/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/span
```

So I defined the following statement in scrapy to get the desired information:

```
plz = response.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/main/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/span/text()').extract()
```

However I was not successful, the string remains empty. What XPath definition should I use instead?

Comment: Can you provide the link that you are trying to scrape. The city values might be fetched by javascript after the page loads.

Comment: http://www.homegate.ch/kaufen/106015544

Comment: It seems as if the city values are embedded in a href tag somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this occurs, this is because browsers correct invalid HTML. How do you fix this? Inspect the (raw) HTML source and write your own XPath that navigate the DOM with the shortest/simplest query.

I scrape a lot of data off of the web and I've never used an XPath as specific as the one you got from the browser. This is for a few reasons:

1. It will fail quickly on invalid HTML or the most basic of hierarchy changes.
2. It contains no identifying data for debugging an issue when the website changes.
3. It's way longer than it should be.

Here's an ***example*** (there are a lot of different XPath queries you could write to find this data, I'd suggest you learning and re-writing this query so there are common themes for XPath queries throughout your project) query for grabbing that element:

```
//div[contains(@class, "detail-address")]//h2/following-sibling::span
```

---

The other main source of this problem is sites that extensively rely on JS to modify what is shown on the screen. Conveniently, though, this would be debugged the same was as above. As soon as you glance at the HTML returned on page load, you would notice that the data you are querying doesn't exist until JS executes. At that point, you would need to do some sort of [headless browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser).

---

Since my answer was essentially "write your own XPath" (rather than relying on the browser), I'll leave some sources:

- [basic XPath introduction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html)
- [list of XPath functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions)
- [XPath Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I'm pretty illiterate with regards to coding, but somehow I managed to alter your proposed statement in a way such that it worked: `//*[@class="h4 title"]/following-sibling::span/text()`

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is manipulated by javascript, so what chrome shows is the xpath after 
the all the stuff has happened.

If all you want is to get the cities, you can get it this way (using scrapy):

```
city_text = response.css('.detail-address span::text').extract_first()
city_code, city_name = city_text.split(maxsplit=1)
```

Or you can manipulate the JSON in CDATA to get all the data you need:

```
cdata_text = response.xpath('//*[@id="tdakv"]/text()').extract_first()
json_str = cdata_text.splitlines()[2]
json_str = json_str[json_str.find('{'):]
data = json.loads(json_str)                # import json
city_code = data['kvzip']
city_name = data['kvplace']
```

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError by using the split method: "split() takes no keyword arguments"

Comment: Leaving the `maxsplit` will cause error if the city name itself contains spaces. But if you're sure there won't be any, go ahead...

Comment: @hjschmid it looks like you can do [`city_text.split(None, 1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).